# GoDaddy URL redirect won't work with affixed www

Tags: 301-redirect, godaddy, domain-forwarding

I have a `mydomain.com` that I recently redirected to `my-new-domain.com` using the forward option 301 in GoDaddy.

It is working fine when I typed in `mydomain.com`, but when I typed it with the affixed `www.mydomain.com`, it won't redirect and just shows "This webpage is not available".

What do I do next? Needed it to work since most of my traffic comes from `www.mydomain.com`.

By the way, the website is at Blogspot if it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> forward option 301 in GoDaddy

I assume this is the [Forwarding without masking](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name) option as detailed on the GoDaddy support page? In which case, they do state part way down that page:

> If you want your visitors to be able to go to your domain name with or without the www prefix, you need to **forward your domain name to use www**.

Answer (score 0):

I have am not too familiar with the GoDaddy option except that we get this question from time to time. It seems this option is somewhat limited. I cannot answer to GoDaddy, but I can offer this.

You can create a blank site with your web host and use .htaccess (assuming Apache) to redirect both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com to my-new-domain.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is a basic example that should work. You can change my-new-domain.com to www.my-new-domain.com if this is what you prefer. I would recommend creating an index.html as a security measure just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a cname record for www pointing to your main A record.  It looks like the website unavailable may be coming because you are missing a cname for WWW in your godaddy dns records.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue like this.After adding forwarding from old domain to my new domain www.new-domain.com. I added one Subdomain forwarding. For that put 'www' in subdomain name and forward to www.new-domain.com

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your domain to work with the www. you need to add the CNAME where it says name put WWW and where it says value(pointing) put @ .  that should do the trick